# Spring Boot + Spring Integration (AMQP)

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, messaging, spring-amqp

I have been reading through the documentation for Spring Integration, but I still can't figure out how to model the following integration:

```
+----------+  --- (request) --> +----------+ --- (request) --> +----------+
| Service1 |                    | RabbitMQ |                   | Service2 |
+----------+  <--- (reply) ---- +----------+ <--- (reply) ---- +----------+
```

Basically what I would like to be able to do is to share an interface between `Service 1` and `Service 2`, say

```
public interface Service2 {
    int sum(int a, int b);

    int subtract(int a, int b);
}
```

and be able to call

`service2proxyInstance.sum(1, 2)`

on some kind auto-generated proxy class inside `Service1`.

From what I read I think I must use an `OutboundGateway` in `Service1` and an `InboundGateway` in `Service2`, but I can't seem to put them together. Could anyone please shed some light and maybe provide a very simple example? All the examples in Spring Integration seem to use XML configuration, but as I am pretty new to Spring and used to annotation-based config I can't read them adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to help you since you have already said everything correctly.

Your service one should be as a `@MessagingGateway` or call such one. That should send a message to a channel for the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` and wait for reply from there. That is really done automatically by `@MessagingGateway`.

You `payload` will be serialized if it is POJO not String or something for JSON-marshalling.

Another application should start from the `AmqpInboundGateway`, send a request to the Service2 for the deserialized `payload` and wait for the reply from there to send back to your Service1 in the end.

Take a look into Spring Integration Java DSL and AMQP [tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/amqp/AmqpTests.java) there.

And share you PoC and your concerns therefor better understanding what's going on.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dumb, but I still don't get it. Also, I forgot to mention that my goal is to have `Service1` and `Service2` as distinct microservices (different JVMs, to start with).

Comment: Right. That's correct. And that's why you have RabbitMQ between your microservices. I still don't see problems with your solution. You just should go ahead! You have a good design and principle understand. Just take a seat and grab keyboard. As I said in the beginning: I don't see any questions because there are answers already.

Comment: The problem here, maybe, is that I have a working implementation of this using Spring Remoting (AMQP) and I'm trying to migrate to Spring Integration (also using AMQP) but I still didn't completely grasp the concepts. I'll have a go at it now and will keep you posted. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Please, take a look to Gary Russell's recent hack which can be useful for you: https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/sleuth295/src/main/java/com/example. That has been done exactly to demonstrate how to replace Spring AMQP Remoting with Spring Integration.

Comment: Great :-) Thank you very much. I will have a look at that!

Comment: It's indeed a great example. Now, the only thing I am missing is exception throwing / handling between the services. I have opened https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/issues/4, maybe you or Gary can please have a look? :-)